# How to match a small vector image in a larger vector image?

Tags: image-processing

I have a small vector image that's a part of a large vector image, but slightly rotated and slightly has a different scale.

Is there a method to find the location of the small image in the large image? Something like correlation in raster images (but I don't want to convert the two images to raster then make correlation).

Answer (score 1):

You want to do is use image pyramids and their variants for this purpose.

Search for rotation-invariant, scale-invariant image pyramids. You will find some good papers on them, here is a paper with the application of such methods called [Steerable pyramids](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/%7Eeero/steerpyr/) to the topic with some good prior-art papers at the end.

Wikipedia page for [Pyramid (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)#Steerable_pyramid):

> #### Steerable pyramid
>
> A steerable pyramid, developed by Simoncelli and others, is an implementation of a multi-scale, multi-orientation band-pass filter bank used for applications including image compression, texture synthesis, and object recognition. It can be thought of as an orientation-selective version of a Laplacian pyramid, in which a bank of steerable filters are used at each level of the pyramid instead of a single Laplacian or Gaussian filter.

Here is [another paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1449/1/012119/pdf) on Image matching using scale, translation and rotation invariant pyramids.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem is that I don't want to convert my vector image to raster, as the large vector image will be quite huge if converted to raster.